# About migration of d3 v3 to d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I have this code of d3 v3:

```
var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
                .size([360, innerRadius])
                .sort(function(a, b) {
                    return d3.descending(a.key, b.key);
                })
                .separation(function separation(a, b) {
                    return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 1.2) / a.depth;
                })
                .value(function(d) {
                    return d.size;
                });
var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();
```

but in d3 v4 I can´t find the equals of the functions or atributes .value, .sort and d3.layout.bundle()

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`d3.layout.cluster` is now `d3.cluster`.

`d3.cluster` now has the size and separation methods.

`d3.layout.bundle` was replaced by [`node.path`](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#node_path) within the d3-hierarchy library. The sort and value methods are also now within [d3-hierarchy](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md), as opposed to `d3.cluster`.

This is the [official changes guide](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) for version 4.